# Asbestos in plaster walls

Tags: plaster, asbestos, lath-and-plaster

I bought my house 4 months ago and it was never disclosed to me that my house contains asbestos. It was built in 1901.

I had some of my plaster, drywall, vinyl flooring and adhesive tested from different rooms. The only thing that came back positive was the vinyl flooring.

I also have vermiculite in my attic but considering I do not have 5k+ to get it all removed I didn't get it tested and am just assuming it's asbestos containing.

We laid new flooring down over the old and will be drywalling over the vermiculite. But my mom brain has me worried of course yet. We tore out a wall yesterday but like I said my plaster came back negative.

Should I be concerned or calm down? It's my first time dealing with a house with wooden lath, and I have to say I'm not a fan.

Comment: You won't know until you get it all tested.

Comment: This question is a matter of opinion (risk tolerance) and is therefore off topic. We're not a discussion forum. Feel free to revise to ask something more specific and objective, or close it and see all the other similar questions.

Comment: Plaster & lathe walls really have absolutely nothing to do with asbestos concerns and can be an absolute joy! (Need to hang a picture? Dive a screw! Doesn't matter much where!) You've got the known asbestos covered, which is the cheapest and a very sensible way of dealing with it. So long as you're not disturbing the old floor or the _possibly_ asbestos containing attic, you've got nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

You tested the **plaster, negative.**

You tore out **plaster** on a wall.

You did not tear out **vinyl flooring** or get into the **vermiculite.**

Asbestos, in place, left alone, is not an issue.

You left your [asbestos & suspected asbestos not tested] alone.

**It's not an issue.**

Comment: Asbestos by itself is not bad.  What is bad is disturbing it causing the small/tiny fibres to go in the air and then into your lungs(masks good).  Undisturbed or covered asbestos can be lived with.

Comment: I used to live in a house near an old asbestos factory [eek!] which had closed 30 years prior. In the decade before I lived there, the entire street had to be 'hoovered' clean - all loft insulation out, the works. It is not 'safe' if just left in loft spaces. In the UK it's not permitted to just cover it either.